# Spring - Autowire multiple Service class from the same Abstract Class

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to find the best way to solve a situation.

I need to choose a Service interface (and its concrete implementation) based on a variable value, in a list of several of them.

The concrete implementation extends an abstract class.

So I have

```
public abstract class AbstractService {

public void method1(){
//do stuff
}

public void method2(){
//do stuff
}

}
```

Then we have

```
 public interface Service1{
void method1();

    void method2();

    void method3();

    void method4();
    }

    public interface Service2 implements Service{
void method1();

    void method2();

    void method3();

    void method4();
    }

    public interface ServiceN implements Service{
void method1();

    void method2();

    void method3();

    void method4();
    }
```

and last, the implementations

```
@Service
public class Service1Implementation extends AbstractService implements Service1 {


}

@Service
public class Service2Implementation extends AbstractService implements Service2 {


}



 @Service
    public class ServiceNImplementation extends AbstractService implements ServiceN {


    }
```

Now, for instance, i need in a controller to decide which service i need based on a variable value.

My idea was to Autowire all the Service interfaces in the controller and then do something like this

```
@Controller
public class Controller{

@Autowired Service1 service1;

@Autowired Service2 service2;

//...

@Autowired ServiceN serviceN

@GetMapping("/")
public String myController(){

int variable;

switch(variable){

case 1:
service1.method()1;
break;
case 2:
service2.method1();
//....
break;
case n:
serviceN.method1();
break();

return "template";

}

}
```

It works... but i have several service class which extends the abstract one, it does not look like it's a well done workflow, is there a way to have it in a lighter way?

Comment: you have not a common interface between  `Service1`, `Service2`, `Service3` interface ?

Comment: not in this configuration, but i could create it, you mean a single interface that all the others implements? And then how can i decide which service i need to call?

Comment: If you can do it, I can write an answer that relies on it.But I don't understand the `getService()` logic. It invokes the `method1()` on the correct instance while the method name is `getService()`. Not very clear.

Comment: Sorry, i would make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the `switch` statement by a `Map` lookup where you will provide as key, the `int` value that you are using in your `switch` and you will get as value from the map the service instance associated to.

This logical :

```
public String myController(){

  int variable = ;

  switch(variable){

    case 1:
     service1.method();
     break;
    case 2:
     service2.method1();
     //....
     break;
   case n:
     serviceN.method1();
     break();    
  }
  ...
}
```

could be replaced by :

```
public String myController(){
   int variable = ...;
   Service service = servicesByCode.get(variable);
   service.method1(); 
  ...
}
```

And as explained, you should add a `Map` field in the class and a method that inits the map after the beans were autowired :

```
private Map<Integer, Service> servicesByCode;

@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    servicesByCode = new HashMap<>();
    servicesByCode.put(1, service1);
    servicesByCode.put(2, service2);
    servicesByCode.put(3, service3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's clear the logic behind this, my problem is to understand which kind of `Service` is in the map, org.hibernate.service.Service? And service1, service2, service3 what are? the implementations or the interfaces?

Comment: @besmart You are welcome. The services are which one you have declared in your spring controller as fields. You have to put them in the map. Glad you get it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Qualifier` for this purpose. Refer [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/)